# What is the range of this function?

Tags: analysis, functions, abelian-groups, function-and-relation-composition, divergence-operator

What is the range of $h$?

$f(x)=4x+1$

$g(x)=(x-1)/3$

Let $h=\{f^n(g^m(1)):n,m\in\mathbb{N}\geq0\}$

What is the range of $h$?

Show that $(2\mathbb{N}-1)\subset H$.

... okay I've done a bit more:

I think the closed forms for $g$ and $f$ are:

$g^m(x)=\frac{x}{3^m}-\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{3^m})$

$f^n(x)=4^nx+\frac{(4^n-1)}{3}$

So

$f^n(g^m(x))=4^n(\frac{x}{3^m}-\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{3^m}))+\frac{4^n-1}{3}$

$h=4^n(\frac{1}{3^m}-\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{3^m}))+\frac{4^n-1}{3}$

What is the range of $h$ for $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$ ?  Show that $(2\mathbb{N}-1)\subset H$.

Please note that I've added the tags *analysis* and *divergence* because i have reason to suspect that the proof that $(2\mathbb{N}-1)\subset H$ may require a proof that one of the functions $f$ or $g$ diverges faster than the other.

If it helps... I think the method required, may be to ask yourself; for any given range of integers from $2^{y-1}$ to $2^y$, what is the least value of $m$ required, to ensure that $h(m,n)$ is exhaustive over $\mathbb{N}$ in that range, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: is $f^n$ the $n$th derivative or $f$ to the power $n$?

Comment: $f^n$ is $n$ iterations of the function $f$. That's why I mention abelian groups... and apologise for the notation!

Comment: So $f^0(x)=x, f^1(x)=4x+1, f^2(x)=16x+5$.

Comment: Ah, so it's a group under _composition_? I don't see why your group is abelian in that case. Simple counterexample: $f(x) = x + 1 g(x) = x^2$.

Comment: The idea is you plug in any $n,m$ from the positive integers so in the case of $n=1, m=1$, the function is $f(g(1))=1$.

Comment: Yes, but I don't think the group is abelian - functions under composition aren't usually abelian groups

Comment: $n=2,m=1$ the function is $f^2(g(1))=5$..

Comment: The problem is not the notation, but the explanation of what the question is.  I suspect that you should explain it in words.  I see that $g$ is a partial function, but how do you apply it to $1$ more than once?  $g(1) = 0$, but $g^2(1) = g(0)$ is not an integer.

Comment: @HewWolff you've got it, except for the integer bit. It doesn't say $g$ has to be an integer.  $g^2(1)=-1/3$.  I only want to show that $\mathbb{N}$ is a subset of the total space covered by $H$.

Comment: @HewWolff an alternative notation might be let $h(n,m)=f^n(g^m(1))$. Show that $\mathbb{N}$ is in the range of $h$.

Comment: Thanks @HewWolff. Do you think that would be better than what I have?  I'm self-taught and not a 'proper' mathematician especially in terms of knowing the language so I'd be happy to put it how it should be. In your notation how would I show $n,m\in \mathbb{N}$ in $h$?

Comment: I think most of the question is clear enough. The part I am unsure of is the mention of abelian groups, which do not really seem to feature anywhere (apart from each set of powers of a function acts as a copy of the integers on wherever you want to apply the functions, but since you want to apply first one and then the other, I don't think this part is very relevant).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft the reason I mentioned Abelian groups is because as I see it (and I may be totally wrong); if you set your $x$ axis as the elements of $F$, it's an abelian group and then if you choose any $f_m$ in $F$, it forms $g^0$ in an abelian group orthogonal to the first generated by $g^n(f_m)$.

Comment: You can get a closed form for the $nth$ iterate of $g$ or $f$ just by "collapsing" the recurrence. It's not very complicated to do and will take the form of a geometric series. Alternatively if you know something about solving linear homogenous recurrence relations these are two very simple ones to solve.

Comment: @Vik78 Thanks, you're talking my language when you say things like "it's not very complicated".  If I learn about closed forms will that enable me to deduce the full range of $f^n(g^m(1))$ for $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @Vik78 thanks for that.  So the closed form for $g^n(x)$ is $((x-1)/3n)-1/3$ I think?

Comment: Sorry that should've been $((x-1)/3^n)-1/3$.

Comment: No, that doesn't look right, sorry. It'll be in the form of a geometric series which has a closed form expression, but that isn't the right closed form. Note that that doesn't give the right answer for the first iterate of $g(1)$. Note that you're subtracting n times, so just figure out how many times each term in the subtraction is divided by 3.

Comment: Yeah I had worked out it was wrong! Will have to come back to it on Thursday.

Comment: @Vik78 okay after much scribbling and no discernible method I have arrived at $g^n=x/3^n+3^{-n}/2-1/2$.

Comment: ...and $f^m(x)=4^mx+(4^m-1)/3$

Comment: Once again these don't give the right answer for the first iterate in either case.

Comment: @Vik78 I'm getting $f^0(1)=1$ and $g^0(1)=1$. What result are you getting that looks wrong?

Comment: @Vik78 and I'm getting $f^1(x)=4x+1$, and $g^1(x)=(x-1)/3$